# UpdatePanel ignores inline script tag

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

I have a lot of places where `<script ....>......</script>` construction goes right after the element it works on (to ensure immediate processing of HTML before it is displayed). Everything works okay.

Now I started to use `asp:UpdatePanel` and some of `<script>` tags are inside in it. I set `Visible="true"` in button click event. But browser does not execute these scripts - it just emits them to resultg DOM as is.

Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock` registers the script on the page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb350750(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: When is it executed? Before page is displayed?

Comment: shouldn't be.  This one will work for that: `ScriptManager.RegisterStartUpScript` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359558(v=vs.110).aspx